# Creation of large files in Google App Engine flexible using PHP

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have project that needs to output hundreds of photos from one template file, compress them into a `.zip` file, and push them to the customer's browser. After that, the `.zip` file can be deleted.

Google App Engine (PHP) does not allow you to write files like you would in a standard web server.

How can this be accomplished with GAE flexible?

Comment: How large are the files? If small enough everything could be done in memory. Otherwise use Compute Engine VMs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have already known, App Engine flexible does not allow you to write files on the system even if it runs on a VM. The reason is that it runs within more Docker containers and you will not have the guarantee that you will find the file.

An alternative for this is to change a bit your workflow and to use [Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/) as an intermediate. You can send the photos directly to Cloud Storage, and the users will be able to download them directly from Cloud Storage. [Here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/php/using-cloud-storage) you have a guide on how to achieve this from App Engine flex for PHP.